# Nesting variables in Apache config

Tags: apache, docker

I'm building a Docker-based Apache proxy, and I'd like the proxied port to be configurable.

I link the containers with `--link ...:proxied`, so Docker makes the environment variables `PROXIED_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR` and `PROXIED_PORT_80_TCP_PORT`. I used `ProxyPass / "http://${PROXIED_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR}:${PROXIED_PORT_80_TCP_PORT}/"` to reverse proxy to port 80.

I'd like the port to be configurable from the command line, when I start the container. I pass the variable as `-e "PORT=..."`, and it is usable as ${PORT} in the Apache config.

I've tried to nest the variables, like `${PROXIED_PORT_${PORT}_TCP_ADDR}` without success, and also using the Define plugin, but still no luck.

Comment: "Environment variables are no longer the recommended method for connecting to linked services" (https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/). The new way to link services together is with docker networking (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

Comment: Thank for the info, I'll take a look.